# Uploading a file through CKAN's API (1.8): How to do it?

Tags: json, bash, file-upload, curl, ckan

I am trying to automate dataset and resource uploading in my CKAN instance. I am using Ubuntu Linux 10.04 64-bit and my CKAN instance version is 1.8.

I can create a new dataset using the command like like so:

```
$ curl http://ckan.installation.com/api/rest/dataset -H "Authorization:<my api key>" -d '{"name": "dataset-name", "title": "The Name of the Dataset"}'
{... JSON text recieved in response, including the id of the dataset ...}
```

Now, how do I go about creating and uploading resources (like image files) in my CKAN instance using the command line?

Thanks!

Comment: Or more specifically, using the JSON API as provided by [CKAN API docs](http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-1.8/api.html).

Comment: Have you tried one of the [CKAN clients](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api.html#clients)?

Comment: If possible, I'd like to use JSON data through CURL. But, I have not tried them, yet.

Comment: Bump. Anyone have an answer for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uploading a file through the FileStore API is somewhat complicated. You'll be better reusing [ckanclient's upload_file method](https://github.com/okfn/ckanclient/blob/master/ckanclient/__init__.py#L546-L583). A simple Python script that uses this could solve your problem of uploading from the command-line.

Or, if you're feeling brave, that's the best place to start understanding how to upload a file using cURL.

Comment: @jonmsawyer did this answer your question? If so might be worth accepting the answer.

Comment: @RufusPollock Vitor's answer is a start, and I've tried using ckanclient's upload_file method, but either I am not doing it right or it doesn't seem to work.